# Como ajustar o tamanho de uma janela Modal Bootstrap genérica de acordo com a View desejada

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, modal

Tenho uma Janela modal bootstrap genérica que abrirá diversas views. O Problema é que cada uma delas terá um tamanho de tela diferente e atualmente, minhas configurações se mantêm fixas(style="width: 800px; height: 500px;")...
Existe alguma maneira de eu mudar as duas partes do código para atenderem a esse requisito?

(Modal Genérica onde todas as Views são abertas)

```js
<div class="modal fade modal-primary" id="modalGenerica" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="contentModal"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(Exemplo de uma view com partes da estrutura da Modal)

```js
@model Retaguarda.Application.ViewModels.CustomerViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Register new Customer";
    Layout = null;
}
<div>
    <form asp-action="Create">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        
            <div class="modal-shadow">
                <div class="modal-header modal-header-primary">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title text-center"> @ViewData["Title"] </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <vc:summary />
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Name" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Email" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="BirthDate" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <input asp-for="BirthDate" class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="BirthDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <select data-plugin="selectpicker" id="mySelect2" data-style="btn-primary">
                                    <option>Mustard</option>
                                    <option>Ketchup</option>
                                    <option>Relish</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success" />
                            <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-info">Back to List</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            
    </form>
</div>



<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script>
    //Resolve problema de exibição no Modal
    $('#mySelect2').selectpicker({
        dropdownParent: $('#modalGenerica')
    });
</script>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A modal ocupa a view toda?

Comment: tah ok. Digamos que a view tenha 1366x768... qual seria o tamanho da modal?

Comment: Eu atualizei o Post com a imagem da modal conforme o código que citei. Há views que terão mais campos e precisarão de um tamanho que ocupe o dobro ou mais de espaço...

Comment: Se for maior que a altura da view, terá barra de rolagem?

Comment: Eu não estava pensando neste detalhe de resolução... É que não manjo muito bem desse assunto... O Ruim é que isso depende da resolução de tela de cada pc que acessar...

Comment: Sim... Com Barra de Rolagem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode usar uma modal com dimensões responsivas baseadas na view (veja comentários no CSS). Exemplo:

```css
.modal-content{
   height: 60%; /*altura da modal*/
}

.modal-dialog{
   max-width: 50%; /*largura da modal*/
   height: 100%; /*altura da view da modal (não alterar)*/
   margin: 0 auto !important; /*centralizar modal horizontalmente*/
}

#contentModal{
    overflow: auto; /*habilita o overflow no corpo da modal*/
}

#modalGenerica{
   overflow: hidden; /*evitar overflow da view da modal*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGenerica">
  Abrir modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade modal-primary" id="modalGenerica" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="contentModal">
               Conteúdo da modal
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado @dvd!!!!! Entendi, sua sugestão. Em relação ao css citado, eu posso criá-lo em um arquivo *.css e depois referenciá-lo na minha page que funcionará certinho?

Comment: Sim, é possível. Mas vc também pode colocar direto nas divs se quiser tb.

Comment: Saquei... É que o sistema será bastante grande com muitas telas e para não ter que mexer em uma por uma prefiro centralizar essas informações em um local, pois o dia que precisar mexer, basta configurar uma vez... Obrigado pela força @dvd!!! Um abraço!